# Unable to boot from 128gb usb

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb

I have used Unetbootin to install Ubuntu Gnome on 2 usb sticks, 128gb and 2gb.
The problem is that when I enter the boot menu only the 2gb stick is visible. No matter if I unplug and plug in again, plug in only the 128, exchange the ports or other things, I cannot see the 128 in the boot priority menu. Of course I can use it as usb stick for file transfer so it is not broken but I need it as a bootable Ubuntu.

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I am going to take a wild guess that this is likely a BIOS level USB driver problem.  Have you tried a smaller size then 128GB but larger then 2GB?

Comment: Yes, 8gb and it is working

Comment: 1) Does it work as expected in another computer?  2) Did you buy the stick from a reputable distributor/reseller (there are lots of counterfeit and junk USB sticks out there fro sale on places like eBay)?   3) Going on what Ramhound is suggesting, have you tried updating your BIOS?  If your current version one is older than 128GB flash drives, then it may not support them.

Comment: My usb (the invisible one) is from Winten, I bought in on Amazon. I have not tried it on another pc. Regarding the BIOS, the pc has less than one year and it has already a double partition on the disk, starting with GRUB. I fear that updating the BIOS would destroy everything

Comment: "I fear that updating the BIOS would destroy everything" then make a backup first, or take it to a professional who isn't afraid of fixing the computer.

Comment: but why should I update the bios? the pc is almost new, why should it have an old bios?

Comment: I assume the contents of the drive is seen when your within an operating system?  If thats the case the only suggestion is to partition the drive into say a 16GB partition and see if that works.  If it does then you have verified the problem is that your BIOS is unable to detect USB drives beyond a certain size.

Comment: Because motherboards when they are shipped takes several weeks to reach the retail location they are sold at. This mean out of the gate the BIOS is likely not current the day you purchase it ( even if its the day its released ).  Something is not working as expected this is the **exact** reason you update stuff like your BIOS.

Comment: ok, assume the problem is that, the BIOS has nothing to do with GRUB or Windows bootloader, it should be safe to just update it, right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in the boot menu I had to enable the boot os CSM and UEFI, not only UEFI. Now the usb is totally visible and bootable.

Thanks for your help